# Missing file [Qt]

Tags: qt

I'm successfully going through proccess of building an application in Qt but when I try to run .exe file by double clicking on it (outside of qt) I'm getting an error saying:
"The program can't start because mingwm10.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem."
I checked for this file and I found it, so I think there is some path to be set in qt, but I don't know neither where and how to do it. Could anyone explain to me how to do it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to add the directory containing mingwm10.dll to your PATH environment variable. I am surprised this was not configured correctly when you installed Qt/MinGW.

Control Panel -> System -> Advanced -> Environment Variables -> PATH

Answer (score 3):

This isn't something that should be set in Qt. Your application is looking for a DLL it can't find, `mingwm10.dll`. You can either copy the DLL (and it's dependencies if there are any) near your .exe, or add the directory it's in to the environment variable `PATH`.

Comment: Very true... And he will have to copy a few Qt dll in the release folder as well... I think copying all the dlls is a better solution if he wants to simply launches and share his application...

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the location where your Qt application is installed and then navigate to "..\Qt\5.11.3\mingw53_32\bin" directory. The search for the missing .dll files, copy them to the location where your .exe file is situated and then re-run the application. If more than one files are missing try the same for them.